# Using loop to measure execution time of cuFFT, the relationship between time and how many loops is not linear

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2012, cuda, fft

Basically I want to measure the time cost by cuFFT function by putting the cuFFT execution function in a for loop, here is the code I used first time (This is the simple example used in the Nvidia website for CUDA):

By the way, my CPU is Intel I7-3630QM 2.40GHz, and GPU is Nvidia NVS 5200M. The platform I used is Visual Studio 2012 and CUDA 5.5, operation system is Windows 7, 64 bits.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cufft.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#define NX 1024
#define NY 1024

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int i;
int Iter;
cufftHandle plan;//A data structure named plan containing all information needed for Fourier Transform.
cufftComplex *data1;//data structure to store the real value and complex value of the input and output of Fourier Transform.

cudaMalloc((void**)&data1, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*NY);//Prepare the NX*NY 2D Fourier Transform by alloc input values on GPU Memory

cufftPlan2d(&plan, NX, NY, CUFFT_C2C);//Prepare 2D Fourier Transform (NX*NY), type is C2C that is complex to complex.

Iter = 1000;

clock_t begin, end;
double cost;
begin = clock();

for (i = 0;i <Iter;i++){

    cufftExecC2C(plan, data1, data1, CUFFT_FORWARD);//Execute the Fourier Transform with input data in data1 and output result to data1, CUFFT_FORWARD means it is FFT not iFFT.
}
end = clock();
cost = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
printf("%lf seconds\n", cost);

cufftDestroy(plan);
cudaFree(data1);

return 0;
}
```

This program returns the time normally 0.030s, if I change the value of Iter (how many loops) to 1100, the results turned to be 0.033s, and if Iter = 1200, the result is 0.036s, which seems linear.

This keeps correct until the Iter = 1500, the time when Iter = 1500 is 0.195s,when Iter = 1600, time = 0.431s.

I don't understand why the time cost is like this, anyone can help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without knowing anything about what cufftExecC2C does or how it works, I'm tempted to say it is a cache effect :)

Comment: I will add the manpange for the function used in the code right now, but if there is cache for the results, the time I got is actually not correct because actually there are not that many calculations but just getting results from cache?

Comment: So it looks like you're measuring execution time for the entire program, but you are probably only interested in execution time for your main loop - is that right? If so, can you put any instrumentation to measure time just around the loop, to make sure the jump is not due to something extraneous..

Comment: Well I was measuring the time for the loop and divided the time by how many loops. The start and end timer is set just before and after the loop in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize();  // add this line
end = clock();
```

And I believe you'll get sane results.

The CUFFT functions are asynchronous so they can support streamed overlap of copy and compute.  That means they return before the underlying GPU operation is complete.  So your for-loop is in effect queueing up a large number of transforms to be performed one after the other.  But they are not necessarily finished by the time you complete your timing.  The complex behavior you are observing I believe is related to exceeding an internal queue depth of the number of kernel launches that can be queued up, before additional requests must wait for queue slots to open up.  But that isn't the central issue.

The central issue is that your timing method is flawed.  This is just another example of the dangers inherent in using host-based timing methods to time asynchronous GPU activity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I am not sure I understand all, hope you can help. 
Firstly, I added the function cudaDeviceSynchronize(); and results seems sane, the time for 100 loops is 0.246s. 
Secondly, cudaDeviceSynchronize() function is used to block until the device has completed all preceding requested tasks according to CUDA manpage, which means in a loop, the cuFFT function is called one by one so at anytime the calculation resource of GPU is not fully used. The result I got is not actually the maximum speed my GPU can achieve. Is this correct?

Comment: No.  You're not grasping the idea of asynchronous execution.  The `cufftExecC2C` operation returns control to the host thread *before the underlying FFT is complete*.  The host thread is your for-loop, so your for loop continues and requests another FFT before the first one is complete, and so on.  These additional requests stack up in a queue.  Eventually you get to the end of the for-loop, but the FFT operations requested are not complete.  The `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` operation ensures that all requested operations are complete before you finish your timing.

Comment: OK, now I understand, then you said this timing method is flawed, if I added the cudaDeviceSynchronize(), is it still flawed ?

Comment: No, that makes it valid.  By that I mean, if you put the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` barrier after your cuda code, then you can be sure that host-based timing will capture the time for both the intervening host code *and* the intervening CUDA (GPU) code.  Presumably that is your intent, so that makes the timing method valid.

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you for your patience and all your answer!